# Positive scalar curvature in dimension 4

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds

Let $M^n$ be a compact simply connected spin manifold.

Gromov, Lawson, and Stolz proved that if $n\geq 5$, then $M$ admits a metric of positive scalar curvature iff $\alpha(M)=0$.

**Question:** What happens in dimension 4?

1. Are there compact simply connected spin manifolds of dimension 4 which have a metric of positive scalar curvature and $\alpha(M)\neq 0$?
2. Are there compact simply connected spin manifolds of dimension 4 which have $\alpha(M)=0$ but no metric of positive scalar curvature?
3. What are necessary and/or sufficient conditions for a compact simply connected spin 4-manifold to have a metric with positive scalar curvature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$1.$ Lichnerowicz proved that if $M$ is a closed spin manifold which admits a positive scalar curvature metric, then $\hat{A}(M) = 0$. In dimensions $4k$, $\alpha(M) = 2\hat{A}(M)$, so it follows that $\alpha(M) = 0$. In fact, Hitchin proved that $\alpha(M) = 0$, regardless of dimension.

$2.$ In dimension four, $\hat{A}(M) = -\frac{1}{24}p_1(M) = -\frac{1}{8}\tau(M)$, so $\alpha(M) = 0$ if and only if $\tau(M) = 0$. If $M$ is a simply connected, closed, spin four-manifold with signature zero, then by Freedman's classification, there is an integer $k \geq 0$ such that $M$ is homeomorphic to $k(S^2\times S^2)$, the connected sum of $k$ copies of $S^2\times S^2$; note, the connected sum of zero copies of $S^2\times S^2$ is defined to be $S^4$. If $M$ is *diffeomorphic* to $k(S^2\times S^2)$, then $M$ admits positive scalar curvature metrics. Said another way, the topological manifolds $k(S^2\times S^2)$ all admit positive scalar curvature *for their standard smooth structure*.

A closed four-manifold can potentially admit a countably infinite number of smooth structures, and the existence of a positive scalar curvature metric depends on which smooth structure you choose. So it is possible that for some choice of $k$ and some choice of smooth structure on $k(S^2\times S^2)$, there does not admit a positive scalar curvature metric. Such examples exist. In [*Hirzebruch Surfaces: Degenerations, Related Braid Monodromy, Galois Covers*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904090.pdf) ([MR 1720873](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1720873)), Teicher constructs examples of simply connected general-type complex surfaces which are spin and have signature zero; see Theorem $5.8$. These are homeomorphic to $k(S^2\times S^2)$ for some $k$, but general type surfaces do not admit positive scalar curvature metrics.

$3.$ In dimension four, unlike in other dimensions, there are gauge theoretic obstructions to the existence of positive scalar curvature metrics. In particular, on a closed smooth four-manifold with $b^+ \geq 2$, the existence of a positive scalar curvature metric implies that all of its Seiberg-Witten invariants vanish. This is a necessary condition, but it is not sufficient. Note that these invariants are usually too complicated to calculate, except in ideal situations such as when the four-manifold in question is the underlying four-manifold of a Kähler surface.

Comment: I think that the link `http://www.ams.org.proxy.library.stonybrook.edu/books/conm/241/3642/conm241-3642.pdf` only works for people from this particular university. Would `http://www.ams.org/books/conm/241/3642/conm241-3642.pdf` be the correct link? Although looking at links from http://www.ams.org/books/conm/241/ (which is accessible to me), it seems that links to individual articles are behind paywall.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I agree. I have changed the link to the arXiv version, but have kept the MathSciNet link for anyone that wants to (and can) consult the published version.